# Delete rows attending to multiplus conditions and null cels

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, isnull, drop

I have a df and I would like to delete all rows attending to the conditions:

1. Column A and are null
2. Column C is equal to "FALSE"

That is what I have tried until now, but no rows were deleted, so I believe something is wrong:

`df = df.drop(df[(df.ret.isnull()) & (df.mv_lag.isnull())& (df.overall_filter == "FALSE")].index)`

Comment: could you include some sample for testing?

Comment: `df[df['A'].notna() & df['C'].ne('FALSE')]`?